# validate record count in header

Tags: shell-script

I am trying to write a script that should verify  total detail records equal to the `Record_count` in header record, If not throw an error

sample data

```
0001  HD  SAP _AP Distribution  20150615  131723  000003  00000003   

detail record 1
detail record 2
detail record 3
```

In the header `00000003` is the record count

Comment: Please [edit] your question and: i) show us your desired output; ii) explain what the record count is. Will it always be the last word on the first line? Also, can there be many records in the file? Will the header always start with a number? Will the records always start with `detail`?

Answer (score 4):

Using `awk`

```
awk '! /^detail/ && /.+/ {max=$9} /^detail record/ {count++} END {if (max == count) { print "ok, "max" = "count} else { print "not ok, "max" != "count }}' foo
```

Or as bash script

```
#!/bin/bash
retValue=$(awk '! /^detail/ && /.+/ {max=$9} /^detail record/ {count++} END {if (max != count) { print "1" }}' "$1")

if [[ "$retValue" -eq 1 ]]; then
    exit 1
fi

exit 0
```

Start the script with:

```
<script_name> <data_file>
```

---

*Example*

```
% cat foo                                                                    
0001  HD  SAP _AP Distribution  20150615  131723  000003  00000003   

detail record 1
detail record 2
detail record 3

% awk '! /^detail/ && /.+/ {max=$9} /^detail record/ {count++} END {if (max == count) { print "ok, "max" = "count} else { print "not ok, "max" != "count }}' foo
ok, 00000003 = 3

% cat bar
0001  HD  SAP _AP Distribution  20150615  131723  000003  00000004   

detail record 1
detail record 2
detail record 3

% awk '! /^detail/ && /.+/ {max=$9} /^detail record/ {count++} END {if (max == count) { print "ok, "max" = "count} else { print "not ok, "max" != "count }}' bar
not ok, 00000004 != 3
```

Answer (score 2):

Shortened `awk` script which expects an input formatted exactly as your example (it [merely] compares the number contained in the 9th field of the first line against the total number of lines minus two):

```
< in awk 'NR==1 {c=$9} END {if (c==FNR-2) print "ok"; else print "ko"}'
```

Comment: @user86683 If this answer solved your issue, please take a moment and [accept it](http://unix.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers) by clicking on the check mark to the left. That will mark the question as answered and is the way thanks are expressed on the Stack Exchange sites.